# Windows server 2003 TS printer redirection

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, printing

I can't seem to get my printer  redirected in Terminal Service mode.

1) I've installed the driver on the Window 2003 server

2) Enabled the "Windows printer mapping" in RDP-TCP properties

But still no printer can be found in my Terminal Session.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in the System event log on the server after you've logged in to a TS session, there should be several events recorded that should give you some clues. Look for events from sources Print and TermServDevices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The printer installed on your remote machine and the server are for the same model.
Sometimes it helps to use a common "generic' driver (aka HP4 for laser printers that speak PCL)

2) Windows printer mapping should be unchecked for it to be enabled.

On the remote desktop login, go to Options and  take a look at the Local Resources tab and make sure Printers is checked.

Comment: (2) should be unchecked? did u mean checked?

Comment: Unchecked. In the Client Settings Tab the wording is: "Disable the following:" So you check what you want DISabled. By the way. On mine, LPT port mapping, Audio Mapping and COM port mapping are CHECKED. Everything else is UNChecked. And my printers work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If your printer connected to USB (or network port) try to configure client settings for ports redirection as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302361)

And make sure you have exactly the same drivers installed on TS as used for local printer you want to redirect to remote session.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "server properties" in Printers and Faxes, and check that driver name on your computer and on the remote desktop are EXACTLY the same. If not, your printer won't be redirected because windows won't find the driver - and it will log an error in the system log, from TermServDevices (like someone already pointed out).